# Python Logging is Blocking: Datadog

Tags: python, logging, python-asyncio

There's a custom log handler in Python called `DataDogCustomLogHandler`.

This is the function to initialise the logger:

```
os.environ["DD_API_KEY"] = 'XXXXX'
os.environ["DD_SITE"] = 'XXXXX'
host_name = socket.gethostname()


def init_datadog_logging(service_name: str = None, env_name: str = None, min_log_level: int = logging.INFO):
    tags = f'service: {service_name}, host: {host_name}, environment: {env_name}'
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(min_log_level)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    if env_name == 'UAT' or env_name == 'Production':
        datadog_custom_handler = DatadogCustomLogHandler(tags=tags, service=service_name, level=min_log_level)
        logger.addHandler(datadog_custom_handler)
```

I have an async function that grabs data using `aiohttp`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def http_get(url: str) -> JSONObject:
    logger.info(f'Getting data from {url}')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

In my `main` function I run this:

```
init_datadog_logging('log.test', 'UAT', min_log_level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def main_async() -> None:
    time_before = time.perf_counter()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for date in dates:
            url = BASE_URL + date
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(http_get(url)))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    logger.info(f'Total time taken: {time.perf_counter() - time_before}')

asyncio.run(main_async())
```

It takes 0.97 seconds without the `logger`, but as soon as I compute `logger.info` it becomes about 8 seconds. How do I unblock the `logging` library? Or is there a better way to send datadog logs via http without blocking in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can start by looking into [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block) of the Python documentation. Basically, you can configure logging so that the handler used doesn't block, by writing to a queue and returning - the blocking code runs in (for example) a separate thread. Do you know if the DataDog handlers you've currently configured block, and if so, on what they block?